# Solr not working while running CKAN over HTTPs using nginx and apache

Tags: ckan

I am running CKAN v2.7.2 over HTTPs using Apache and have configured Nginx-reverse proxy to access CKAN.Thus,I am accessing CKAN using Nginx only.

All the three components (CKAN,Apache,Nginx are running on docker).

The CKAN page is being loaded however,I get the following error logs in apache ckan_default.conf.error.log

```
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
[wsgi:error] [pid 93:tid 139753652762368] ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8983): Max retries exceeded with url: /solr/ckan/select/?s

ERROR [pysolr] Failed to connect to server at 
'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ckan/select/?sort=score+desc%2C+metadata

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 366, in _send_request
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8983): Max retries exceeded with url: /solr/ckan/s
```

Comment: What's your production.ini file have for the solr url?  `solr_url=http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr`?  Actually, maybe you don't modify this from a docker install?

Comment: In production.ini I have solr_url = http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ckan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reach solr from ckan because they are running in two different container on the same virtual network.

If you run a container, a bridged network will be created by default.

```
$ hostname -i
::1 127.0.0.1
$ docker run --rm alpine hostname -i
172.17.0.2
```

If container share the same network (like when you usually run containers with `docker-compose`, you can connect from one to the other using the name of the last one.

In your case, you should probably connect to `http://solr:8983/solr/ckan`.